# usage of underscore js in html meteor blaze project

Tags: meteor, underscore.js, meteor-blaze

what is the difference between.

```
      <span class="icon-plus"></span>
        {{_ "New List"}}
      </a>
```

and

```
      <span class="icon-plus"></span>
        New List 
      </a>
```

I know usage of _ in js files but here _ is in html
by the way both of them seem like working identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{_ ...}}` calls the helper named `_`.  As Denis stated if you've done `meteor add tap:i18n` then it would call the helper from the [tap:i18n package](https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n).

You could also register a helper yourself. I've done this to give myself underscore access in templates:

`Template.registerHelper('_', (method, arr) => _[method](arr));`

Answer (score 1):

These are unrelated.

`_` in js usually references the `http://underscorejs.org/` library.

`_` in your html template likely references a helper installed by the `https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n` package/library for internationalization.